# Alternate way to set credentials for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: go, google-vision

I've a Go app that uses the *Google Vision API* and *Google Video intelligence* API.
To enter my credentials, I set the environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. To do so, I assign a file path to this variable that points to the directory where my credentials are stored in.

*Problem:*

My credentials are *not* initially saved in a file. Instead they are assigned to a  string variable inside my app.
As a workaround, I store that value to a temporary file and then assign it's path to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, like described above.

*Question:*

Is it possible to set API credentials for `cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1` without this file?

Answer (score 0):

i do not know how it on Google Vision Api, but for the Google Sheets Api there is such stuff:

```
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
```

so b is a slice taken from the file `credentials.json` u can just take it from any other place by yourself